# Mac NFS connection to Open-E NAS

Tags: networking, macos, permissions, nas, nfs

I am part of a team of video editors, and our shared storage system has been down for more than a week. Over the course of two days of on-site service, the vendor that installed the system seems to have solved the initial problem (first some folders lacked permissions for some users, and then suddenly all users had no permission for the NAS volume as a whole) but seems to have created another problem. The current issue is that one of 8 connected systems is able to connect, with no problems either with the connection or with the permissions, but the other 7 systems cannot connect, in various forms. On all of those 7 systems, I am using the "Connect to Server" command within MacOS, and attempting to connect to "nfs://(server IP)/(share name)", but depending on which system I get one of the following errors:

1. Click connect, another screen flashes up and disappears (so fast I can't see what it is), and the system plays the sound that usually means a server is connected, but the connection never happens.
2. Click connect, and a progress bar appears, sits there for a while, and then a window appears that says "the connection to the server was interrupted" (again playing the same "connected" sound), but the connection never seems to exist
3. On one system, the same message appears as when there was a permissions issue, "Could not connect to server. You do not have permission to access this server."

On at least one of the problem systems, I can ping the server address in the terminal. I can ping the switch address in the terminal. I also attempted to mount the NFS share from the terminal using `sudo mount -t (server address):/(share name)`. `showmount -e (server address)` shows /(share name) but it is not listed in /Volumes and I cannot connect to it in any meaningful way.

Is there anything else I should try here?